# Setting up form tracking with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to set up a custom script for tracking a users click through on a form submission field. This is what I've got so far. As the user navigates down through the form fields the counter variable (base) totals up how far along the path the user has reached. I want to send the results off when the user leaves the page by sending out the base variable. I'm thinking of using the .unload function in jQuery. However for some reason unload isn't responding the way I think it should. Any ideas?

```
var base = 0; //declares a variable of 0. This should refresh when a new user lands on the form page. 

function checkPath(fieldNo, path) { //this function should check the current base value of the base variable vs the current fieldNo
    if (fieldNo >= path) { //checks to see if base if lower than fieldNo
        base = fieldNo; //if true, base is set to current fieldNo 
        return base;
    } else {
        return base; //if false, simply returns base. 
    }
};

$('#order_customer_fields_forename').focus(function () { //when the form box is selected should run checkPath then alert result. 
    checkPath(1, base);
});
$('#order_customer_fields_surname').focus(function () {
    checkPath(2, base);
});
$('#order_customer_fields_postcode').focus(function () {
    checkPath(3, base);
});
$('#order_customer_fields_address1').focus(function () {
    checkPath(4, base);
});
$('#order_customer_fields_address2').focus(function () {
    checkPath(5, base);
});

$(window).unload(function () {
    alert(base);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `unload` event fires too late for the effect you need. You should try using the `onbeforeunload` event using either vanilla Javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    // Your code here
};
```

Or jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // Your code here
});
```

Either way, you should be aware that this is not an ideal solution for what you are trying to achieve. This event is implemented unevenly across browsers. Chrome seems to be the most restrictive, and IE the most permissive, in its implementation.

A different direction you may want to take is sending the data to the server by XHR whenever the user completes a field.